# update 2nd table if id exist in table 1 , mysql update statement

Tags: mysql

table structure

table 1

```
userid   username 
 1        joe
 2        matt
```

table 2

```
 userid      username 
  1
```

Need to update  username in table2 if user id is match table 1
like select userid from table 1 if exist  in table 2 then update username in table 2 ( username fetched from table 1 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it by joining the tables using `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE table2 a 
       INNER JOIN table1 b
          ON a.userid = b.userid
SET    a.username = b.username
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36961/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE table2 a 
       INNER JOIN table1 b
          ON a.userid = b.userid
       SET a.username = b.username
```